# Populating html with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Ive been trying to learn Javascript OOP so i made a quiz. However for some reason my html is not being populated with the questions and answers I made. I cannot figure out the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Edgy Quiz</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<h1>In a world where everyone is looking to stand out from the crowd</h1>
<h2>Does the extend of your own edginess confuse you?</h2>
<h3>Well this scientifically proven personality test was built for you!</h3>
<div class="grid">
  <div id="quiz">
  <h4>How edgy are you?</h4>
  <hr style="margin-top: 20px">

  <p id="question"></p>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button id="btn0"><span id="choice0"></span></button>
    <button id="btn1"><span id="choice1"></span></button>
    <button id="btn2"><span id="choice2"></span></button>
    <button id="btn3"><span id="choice3"></span></button>
    </div>
    <hr style="margin-top: 50px">
    <footer>
      <p id="progress">Question x of y.</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


$(window).load(function() {

function Question(text, choices, answer) {
    this.text = text;
    this.choices = choices;
    this.answer = answer;
  }

  Question.prototype.correctAnswer = function(choice) {
    return choice === this.answer;
  }

function Quiz(questions) {
  this.score = 0;
  this.questions = questions;
  this.questionIndex = 0;
}

Quiz.prototype.getQuestionIndex = function() {
  return this.questions[this.questionIndex];
}

Quiz.prototype.isEnded = function() {
  return this.questions.length === this.questionIndex;
}

Quiz.prototype.guess = function(answer) {
  if (this.getQuestionIndex().correctAnswer(answer)) {
    this.score++;
  }
  this.questionIndex++;
}

function populate() {
  if(quiz.isEnded()) {
    showScores();
  }
  else {
    var element = document.getElementById("question");
    element.innerHTML = quiz.getQuestionIndex().text;
    var choices = quiz.getQuestionIndex().choices;
    for(var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
      var element = document.getElementById("choice" + i);
      element.innerHTML = choices[i];
      guess("btn" + i, choices[i]);
    }
    showProgress();
  }
}

function guess(id, guess) {
  var button = document.getElementById(id);
  button.onclick = function () {
    quiz.guess(guess);
    populate();
  }
}

function showProgress () {
  var currentQuestionNumber = quiz.questionIndex + 1;
  var element = document.getElementById("progress");
  element.innerHTML = "Question " + currentQuestionNumber + "of " + 
quiz.questions.length;
}

 function showScores() {
  var gameOverHtml = "<h1>Result</h1>";
  gameOverHtml += "<h2 id='score'>Your score: ' + quiz.score + '</h2>";
  var element = document.getElementById("quiz");
  element.innerHTML = gameOverHtml;
}

var questions = [
new Question ("How have you discovered this test?", ["I was bored browsing 
online", "I want to see how edgy I am", "Im a friend doing it out of 
Sympathy", "Im looking at this weirdo's portfolio"], "Im looking at this 
weirdo's portfolio"),
new Question ("How edgy do you think you are?", ["Extremely edgy", "Im very 
mainstream", "What does edgy even mean?", "I don't do labels"], "I don't do 
labels"),
new Question ("Of these colors which is your favourite?", ["Blue", "Orange", 
"Majenta", "Black"], ""),
new Question ("Could you bring yourself to hurt a living thing?", ["Only if 
it hurt me first", "I hurt stuff for fun", "No never how could you im a 
vegan", "I hurt myself all the time"], "I hurt myself all the time"),
new Question ("If someone tickled you how would you respond?", ["Tickle 
fight", "Run away", "Punch them in the face", "Write a song"], "Write a 
song"),
];

var quiz = new Quiz(questions);

populate();

});
```

Comment: What does the browser console say? Use the development tools of your browser or `firebug` for firefox to make errors visible. Also use breakpoints and `console.log('I was here. value is'+val)` to debug your code.

Comment: In your `questions`, it looks like you don't close the strings before going to a new line. Is that just how it looks on this site, or is your code actually like that? Because that is an error otherwise.

Comment: Ok i actually just worked it out. For some reason there was an error with the $(window).load(function(). so i just deleted it and the html is being populated.

Comment: I have a new problem though now. At the end of the quiz it should display the score but instead displays Your score: ' + quiz.score + '

Comment: @AlexanderJohnston you need to use double quotes : `gameOverHtml += "<h2 id='score'>Your score: " + quiz.score + "</h2>";`

Comment: Oh, and the issue you had with `$(window).load(function()` - do you just not have JQuery? I don't see a script tag for it in your HTML. [This plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/dtnbGWqKPqBpdLzcjcuU?p=preview) runs fine for me...

Comment: Im relatively new to coding so forgive my ineptitude. Do you always have to load jQuery? I just wanted to practice vanilla javascript.

Comment: Thats odd the plunker runs fine. Good tool btw thanks. I dont see the  ' + quiz.score + ' bug in plunker...

Comment: ahh thanks the double quotes. legend. All working now, you guys have been a great help thanks a bunch!