# create arrays containing questions, answers and the right answer

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a quiz game, and what I would like to achieve is to include a template form in which I can add questions and answers.

Could someone tip me on how to separate the file/what files I need to create?

Instead of hard-coding the questions, I would like to be able and adjust them on the browser.

```
// create questions
var questions = [
    new Question("What used to be the currency of Italy?",["lira","pesos","forint", "dolar"], "lira"),
    new Question("In what country was pesetas the currency??", ["Spain", "France", "Greece", "Germany"], "Spain"),
    new Question("Which country is the largest producer of olive oil?", ["Spain", "France","Greece", "Italy"], "Spain"),
    new Question("What is the world s largest office building?", ["Pentagon", "Boieng", "duPortage", "CMG"], "Pentagon"),
    new Question("What is the main component in glass?", ["Sand", "Soil", "Oil", "Wood"], "Sand")
];
```

Comment: Can you give more example of what you're looking for? Create HTML form? How to process said form?

Comment: so i created a form in html, a json file i would like to create these questions, answers and rightAnswer. these will be sent to json file from which i pull the data from.

Comment: that s a link with an almost identical code however, instead of having static questions i want to be able and edit them. i thought json would be a good solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43942852/populating-html-with-javascript

Comment: json file would look like this, could you help me with the java code
"questions": [
  "Questions",
  {
   
   "text": "What used to be the currency of Italy?",
   "answer": "lira",
   "choices": {
    "A": "lira",
    "B": "pesos",
    "C": "forint",
    "D": "dolar"
   }
   
   
  },
  {
   "text": "In what country was pesetas the currency?",
   "answer": "Spain",
   "coices": {
    "A": "Spain",
    "B": "France",
    "C": "Greece",
    "D": "Germany"
   }
  }
 ]

Comment: You should update your question to add the relevant javascript and HTML code you have so far so it's easier to understand your question and help you.

Comment: it is not possible to add such a long code however, i posted a link with the same code here you have a link with almost identical code:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvk1pFNqXaw

Comment: i need to get the submission form to send that data to JSON file and then pull that data into html through js. As you can see in the link the data that is inserted is prefixed, all i want to ad is a way to include questions and pull them from JSON instead
i include in the html a form to add question, 4 choices and 1 right answer just like the code you see above